# how to keep appended html element in page even if you refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to keep appended HTML element in page even if you refresh the page?
So when I click on try it button it creates a new button but when I refresh it disappear how can I solve this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol, so you have to store current number of buttons somewhere and after page load - generate buttons according to this number. Simple solution - local storage.

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner because I am making an admin panel for online store and I need this to add new products and keep them in the page so I am pretty sure I am going to need PHP codes there so I thought maybe there's something I don't know but somebody else does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I know, you can't unless you are using an authentication system (login system) or cookies. Since the page that the browser displays is an HTTP response, every time the page is requested, it sends out the original copy of your code. This is why you need an external/internal system to save the state, displayed or not, for your button.

I would suggest the "cookie" approach first because it is not mandatory to implement an user system and a database table only for that. It is also fairly easy to do compared to the other approach described below.

You could add a simple variable as a cookie and check with JavaScript if it is there, from that, you can display the button or not depending on the cookie.

If you want more information about cookies, here is a link from W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

*If you want however to use a login system (essentially working with sessions), you should add a row in your users table which represents the state of the button.
However, I hardly recommend that since it is hard to implement only for the sake of doing what you are trying to do. You should reset it every time the user log-out and do a bunch of things that I won't go into.*

Comment: Thanks for info. Let me explain more what actually I want so I want to create a dashboard for my online store and want to add products from there what do you recommend how is it done do you have any information about that?

Comment: Before I dive more into it, do you want the customer to add, let's say the products to its cart or the owner to add a new product to sell on the website ? It does make a huge difference depending on the answer...

Comment: No, I will add but I want to make it much easier like make a dashboard and upload photo and write the price and other descriptions and then It get uploaded to products page

Comment: I would suggest you to use a back-end framework such as **Django** in Python, **Rails** in Ruby or even  **Angular**, **React** and all the others in JavaScript. I know this might not be fun to hear but if you are dealing with back-end stuff, such as database (for your uploaded images, user authentication for customers, product information, etc). It is also best for security and and can tell you in the end it is going to save you a lot of time even if it does not seem like it. I have also seen that you used PHP and I known this is possible to do with that but I am not an expert in this field.

Comment: Thanks for Info I will search more about it.
P.S. my reputation is lower than 15 I can't vote

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this pretty easily with the localStorage functions.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
let btn = `<button>CLICK ME</button`

function myFunction(){
    $("body").append(btn)
    localStorage.setItem("wasPageRefreshed" , true)
}

if(localStorage.getItem("wasPageRefreshed")){
    myFunction()
}
```

This way when the `myFunction` function is ran the button is appended and you create a localStorage entry that points to being `true`. The next time the page is refreshed the browser checks if the localStorage item of `wasPageRefreshed` is `true`. If it's true the button you defined as `btn` will be appended.